# Remote Access Error when attempting to create a function to access data on a different server - SQL

Tags: sql-server, function, runtime-error, schema, remote-access

I am trying to build a report (that uses several functions from different servers).

The problem I have is that the majority of functions live on `server1` and 1 function lives on `server2`. I thought I would recreate the singular function that lives on `server2` on the `server1`. The procedure itself lives on `server1` (although I can build this on either server). The problem is that this function that I want to move to `server1` accesses tables and data from `server2` as well.

When in my report I access tables directly across servers I map them with the correct schema server.database.dbo etc ... and I have no problems. However, when attempting to do the same thing with a function, I get the following error:

```
Error: 
Remote access is not allowed from within a schema-bound object.
```

Is this something that is fixable. Any suggestions. 
(one idea I had was to take the function and pull it using just a standard call to the data and dump the data into temp tables) And join it on the appropriate values that way. But I was curious if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema binding is not allowed for objects such as functions or views accessing objects from another database, or in this case server.  If this function needs to be schema-bound you can consider pulling the data into a data warehouse and then operating on it from there.

[MSDN Function Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)